# What is the grammar for language $L=\{a^nb^m : n \neq m-1\}$?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

What is the grammar for language $L = \{ a^nb^m : n\neq m-1\}$?

I only know I have to write grammar for both $ n<m-1 $ and $ n>m-1 $, so this is what I wrote:

- For $n<m-1$:
  \begin{align}
      &S\to Abb \\
      &A\to aAb \mid \lambda
  \end{align}
- For $n>m-1$:
  \begin{align}
      &S\to aaA \\
      &A\to aAb \mid \lambda
  \end{align}

Yet I can not mix them and get a correct grammar for $L$.

Comment: What makes you think that there's a *context-free* grammar for it?

Comment: @Raphael As the question seems to distinguish $<$ and $>$ it seems we have to read $!$ as negation, rather than as factorial.

Comment: PS. I took the liberty of editing both $!=$ and landa.

Comment: @HendrikJan Ahhh, good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split the grammar into two parts for disjoint parts of the language you better take different names for the variables, since they have a different meaning in the two parts.

Answer (score 0):

In your first grammar, change S to X and leave A unchanged. In your second grammar, change S to Y and A to B. Then add S -> X | Y.

And fix your grammars to handle n < m-1 instead of n=m-2 and n>m-1 instead of n = m+2.